# (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in cv2.cvtColor

Tags: python, string, opencv

I tried to use the following code to read the text on the image, but when I run it, I get error.

```
import cv2

image_file = "D:\try.png"
img = cv2.imread(image_file)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
img_erode = cv2.erode(thresh, np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8), iterations=1)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img_erode, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

output = img.copy()

for idx, contour in enumerate(contours):
    (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)

    if hierarchy[0][idx][3] == 0:
        cv2.rectangle(output, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (70, 0, 0), 1)

cv2.imshow("Input", img)
cv2.imshow("Enlarged", img_erode)
cv2.imshow("Output", output)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

and error:

```
line 4, in <module>
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv- 
python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() 
in function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

Comment: Your input image does not exist at the location you have specified or your syntax is wrong for specifying the path. See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-opencv-cv2-imread-method/

Comment: please review [ask]. you need to search for error messages.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you say

```py
image_file = "D:\try.png" # wrong!
```

`\t` is an **escape sequence** for a tabulator symbol. Any backslash in a regular string, combined with the following character, *might* be an escape sequence. `\\` will cause a literal backslash. `\"` will cause a literal quote character. `\n` will cause a newline character. Some other combinations are not recognized escape sequences. They may be taken literally or they may cause the string to be rejected by the language parser or a following step.

You should use "raw" strings ("r-strings") instead:

```py
image_file = r"D:\try.png"
```

Answer (score 0):

The image path seems to be the problem, it works fine if the image path is correct. but you may need to add a line import numpy as np to make it work.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image_file = "/home/pi/Desktop/output2.jpg"
img = cv2.imread(image_file)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
img_erode = cv2.erode(thresh, np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8), iterations=1)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img_erode, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

output = img.copy()

for idx, contour in enumerate(contours):
    (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)

    if hierarchy[0][idx][3] == 0:
        cv2.rectangle(output, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (70, 0, 0), 1)

cv2.imshow("Input", img)
cv2.imshow("Enlarged", img_erode)
cv2.imshow("Output", output)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: numpy has got nothing to do with it and adding the import will make no difference.

Comment: i was trying to run the code and it showed the error saying   
File "tst1.py", line 8, in <module>
    img_erode = cv2.erode(thresh, np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8), iterations=1)
NameError: name 'np' is not defined

so writing  import numpy as np solved it, so i though i might mention it.

Comment: ok granted, importing numpy may be required by the code that comes *after* the actual issue. it won't fix the question's issue though.

Comment: ya true, i was just giving him heads up, the ans you gave is really accurate tho. i am learning a lot just following you ans here in stack overflow.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).